# How to improve this repository design?

Tags: c#, repository, uml, repository-pattern

In my current design, I was creating a repository where, it's composed by a dictionary, where you can set several objects called Foo into a Level (Easy, Medium and Hard). I.E.

- **Level Easy:** Foo1 object, Foo2 object, Foo3 object
- **Level Medium:** Foo4 object
- **Level Hard:** Foo5 object, Foo6 object

And this is my repository:

```
public interface IFoosRepository
{
    void AddFooLevel(Levels level, Foo foo);
    void RemoveFooLevel(Levels level);
    Foo GetProblemFoo(Levels level);
    IEnumerable<Levels> GetFooLevels();
    IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos();
}

public class FoosRepository : IFoosRepository
{
    private IFoosService service;
    private Dictionary<Levels, Foo> _fooLevels = new Dictionary<Levels, Foo>();

    public FoosRepository()
        : this(new FoosService())
    {
    }

    public FoosRepository(IFoosService service)
    {
        this.service = service;

        // Loads data into the _fooLevels
        // ...
    }

    public void AddFooLevel(Levels level, Foo foo)
    {
        _FooLevels.Add(level, foo);
    }

    public void RemoveFooLevel(Levels level)
    {
        _FooLevels.Remove(level);
    }

    public Foo GetProblemFoo(Levels level)
    {
        return _FooLevels[level];
    }

    public IEnumerable<Levels> GetFooLevels()
    {
        return _FooLevels.Keys;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
    {
        return _FooLevels.Values;
    }
}
```

Then, I realized another thing, I need to have a uniqueId like a name for the foos objects. I.E. if I want to have a specific object from a level, I need to set the name to get it.

Now the objects would be like this:

- **Level Easy:** [name:foo1, Foo1 object], [name:foo2, Foo2 object], [name:foo3, Foo3 object]
- **Level Medium:** [name:foo4, Foo4 object]
- **Level Hard:** [name:foo5, Foo5 object], [name:foo7, Foo6 object]

I mean, each name is accompany by a unique name and I guess it'll be the best that this name is not repeated in another more.

And here is when I start to doubt about my first design. My first though was IDictionary>, or maybe I should have to include this id into the Foo attribute, but I guess that's not the best solution.

What should I modify to implement this new feature?

Answer (score 0):

How about nested Dictionaries? Dictionary(of Levels, Dictionary(of String, Foo))

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without knowing more about how your repository is going to be used, but nested dictionaries seem to be what you want.  For example, in your `FoosRepository` class:

```
private IDictionary<Levels,IDictionary<string,Foo> _foos = new Dictionary<Levels,IDictionary<string,Foo>>;
```

Then, for example, your `AddFooLevel` would become:

```
public AddFooLevel( Levels level, string name, Foo foo ) {
  IDictionary<string,Foo> level = null;
  if( _foos.ContainsKey( level ) ) {
    level = _foos[level];
  } else {
    level = new Dictionary<string,Foo>();
    _foos.Add( level );
  }
  level.Add( name, foo );
}
```